# How could a real life apocalypse game draw in most people?

Tags: post-apocalypse, gods, games

A supreme being has finished their renovations of modern day Earth, and has now decided what is needed is monsters, epic quests, magical powers, danger, excitement, and all.

However, they also don't want to force people to go into it, or magically change people so they want it, and want to have this reality side by side with mundane life.

How do they ensure that most people would want to play in such a game and enjoy it more than real life?

## Limitations.

The apocalypse world side by side with modern life must involve danger, monsters, treasure, questing, and epic battles, along with resource limitations and other difficulties common to an apocalypse.

They don't want to break the free will of people who don't want to enter the apocalypse world or use force to make them enter the world.

They want most people, including those who don't like deadly fights, to want to enter this world and enjoy the questing there.

What features should they include in this update of reality that could persuade normal people who don't like murdering things and being in pain and fighting deadly battles to give up their normal jobs and do so?

Better answers will include things that would persuade not just glory seekers and lovers of battle, but normal people who could otherwise live a good life with family and friends.

Comment: Have you read "Ender's Game" by Orson Scott Card?

Comment: I have read that, yes.

Comment: When someone dies in the game, are they dead for real, or there is some respawning/resurrection?

Comment: What does 'most' mean? 50%+1? or 90%?

Comment: Have you watched Squid Game by Netflix?

Comment: Would a Jumanji-esque thing work? Flashy ads, and anyone who buys the game gets zapped into it.

Comment: I have watched squid game, and while they could certainly offer to pay the debt of anyone who plays, not everyone has crippling gambling debt.

They can certainly do Jumanji stuff, if that works.

Comment: A decent chance at a better life. Be it being free from dept, having healthcare, not having to do a job they don't like, getting out of an undesirable life situation. Or the feeling to be able to make a difference.

Comment: Is "apocalypse" over selling the state of the new world a bit? Is the dungeon fantasy world going to end killing everyone inside unless a hero succeeds in saving us all? Heading into a doomed landscape dependent on the "hero" is a bit different than offering a new background to my life as a retail entrepreneur.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Suggest the fates of each world is intertwined

People do a lot to protect themselves. We endure pain, boredom, humiliation, fears and much more, some on a daily basis, just to get by in our real life. The suggestion that you, family, friends or even just strangers won't survive if they lose in the apocalypse world will pull them in. If we look at wars we can see even good people can be coerced into bad things. Milgram experiments or just some modern prisons can show much the same picture.

### Financial gain

Finances are another where people can excell. Maybe you can take some things back from the apocalypse world. It's a dying world anyway, so enrichment or feeding of yourself and loved ones by plundering apocalypse world is all too easily justified. They might just be asked by a company, or get jobs to help in that world.

### Reputation

Sometimes all people want is admiration or attention. It's a great way to act out, impress friends or love interests or release pent up energies.

### Everybody is doing it

Probably most of us remember bitcoin. For me at least everywhere you looked everyone was talking about it for a time. Millions joined not just because of the promise of easy money, but because everybody was doing it. Often without knowledge what they were doing or how things worked they set to work. There's a billion ways this can be done, from the fear if missing out to just seeing everyone with a smart phone so they get one too. My parents should definitely have left that part on the side of the road, but each has this technology that they simply don't understand. Just because everyone has one.

If everybody is hearing about this new reality they might want to see it. If everyone is participating they might do so just to be part of it. Regardless if they don't understand or condone violence. People will make it right in their head. It's literally a different doomed world with monsters. It is all too easily justified. We do it to other people, sometimes even family and friends, just because we see them as different. The gap here is so much bigger.

Answer (score 12):

Quest games do not need only heroes. They also need merchants, healers, monks, blacksmiths and so on.

If the "game version" of life offers better opportunities than the "real version" of life, more and more people will try the switch.

At the end, isn't this how a good part of the population moved to settle in the Americas?

Comment: Since you mention American Colonialism... it is fair to suggest that such a world may come with all the same problems.  Prisoners being forced to this world forming penal camps. Immigrants fleeing religious and ethnic persecution.  Prospectors drawn in by over blown rumors of gold and other precious metals... probably even some human trafficking, though less than colonial America since it will be illegal on this side of things at the very least.

Answer (score 4):

If you agree to play apocalypse world, your heroic exploits are broadcast on TV in the real world. Do enough cool stuff and you get to be famous.

There are drawbacks. You may not be as interesting as you think you are, so you end up with low ratings. Your exploits might have some really humiliating moments which will be on social media for decades to come.

If you skip the fine print in the contract, you may not realize that disease, dismemberment, and death in apocalypse world are all real and will continue if you (or your corpse) returns to the real world.

Answer (score 2):

**Customizable!**

You can customize your experience to match your interests.  For example I would visit such a world but I can't stand people with skinny legs.  Everyone would need to have big legs for me to be interested.

That can be done!  In my version of the world, everyone has big legs and some people (and NPCs, and monsters) have seriously large legs.  Other participants who likewise are interested in big legs will also be represented in my world.

Other worlds might feature all people with googly eyes.  Or a world where you fight monsters by catching them in a ball, and then having them fight for you.  Maybe a world where monsters are funny and even helpful, and the contests involve solving puzzles or mazes.  Or a world where combat involves research and guessing future events,and then predicting them better than your coplayers.

You will advertise the variety of experiences this endeavor can provide.  You will invite people to participate for free or a nominal charge, then monetize participation in varous ways for the people who find it rewarding or who want to participate on a higher level.

It is not a very novel approach I am afraid.

Comment: Offering a lot of customization over the base human experience is a pretty solid incentive to go over, yeah.

Answer (score 2):

**Be a little dishonest**

"The new world offers incredible wealth and opportunity! After getting everything you dreamed of, and even more, you would never want to return to the regular world!"

Show slick ads of the new worlds with people living the lives of kings and heroes. Skip any ugly parts. Institute some kind barrier of acceptance "You must be worthy to join this new world!" - but of course this barrier is just a ploy to make this new world more appealing. As a result, people will start moving into this new world. Of course, once they found that the new world is actually not that glorious, they would want back - but that won't be so easy!

This supreme being must allow *some* travelers back into the old world, but only the ones who would reinforce its image. So the people of the old world would never know the real truth of the new world and would keep trying to go there.

Answer (score 1):

The rewards that can be obtained on the apocalypse side.  Magical sites that grant things like enhanced lifespan.  Most magic stays on the apocalypse side but there are some single-use items that can be brought back.

Your child has cancer, an awful lot of people would go through to find a potion of cure disease that could be brought back.

Answer (score 0):

**Because it is risk free and much more fun than having to sit in the office all day long.**

Gods have granted you an additional life if you join in. If you die in the game you get to continue your old life. If you get severely injured, you will be one piece after you exit. Surely once you die in the game you will never be able to go back. Thus there will be a level of danger in there.

Obviously gods won't allow you to get in and out everyday to go back to your home at night, otherwise it won't be fun at all. But if they allow stays as short as a week or a month, allowing you to take your loot with you back to the real world, there will be tons of people lining up.